# recursing small side of quicksort first

Tags: java, quicksort

I'm trying to debug this code [I found](http://mypathtothe4.blogspot.ca/2013/02/lesson-2-variations-on-quicksort-tail.html) for making a quicksort that sorts the smaller partition first.

```
public static void quicksortSmallSide(int[] a, int p, int r)
{
    int q = p;
    while(p<r)
    {
        q = partition(a,p,r);
        if(q < (p + (r-p)/2))
        {
            quicksortSmallSide(a,p,q);
            p = q+1;
        }
        else
        {
            quicksortSmallSide(a,q+1,r);
            r = q-1;
        }
    }
}
```

The input [20, 19, 20] used to give the wrong output [20, 19, 20] and I realized. I think I fixed it by changing it to the following code, but I don't think it's bug free yet

```
public static void quicksortSmallSide(int[] a, int p, int r)
{
    if(r-p< 1)
        return;
    int q = p;
    while(p<r)
    {
        q = partition(a,p,r);
        if(q < (p + (r-p)/2))
        {
            quicksortSmallSide(a,p,q);
            p = q+1;
        }
        else
        {
            quicksortSmallSide(a,q+1,r);
            r = q-1;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
                    quicksortSmallSide(a,p,q);
}
```

For example
`{70, 24, -74, 9, 58, -61, -86, 7, -78, 11, -73, 13, -93}`
 gets sorted to
`[-93, -86, -74, -73, 7, -61, 9, 11, -78, 24, 58, 13, 70]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not look right so maybe my partition method is slightly different to yours but this code works as I expect. This code does not take into account that there may be more that one instance of the partition value.

```
private static void quickSort(int[] arr, int lo, int hi){
  if(lo >= hi) return;

  int p = partition(arr, lo, hi);

  // modified to choose small partition first

  if((p - lo )<=(hi-p)){
    System.out.println(String.format("Sorting left first %d %d %d",lo,p,hi)) ;
    quickSort(arr, lo, p);
    quickSort(arr, p+1, hi);
  }else {
    System.out.println(String.format("Sorting right first %d %d %d",lo,p,hi)) ;
    quickSort(arr, p+1, hi);
    quickSort(arr, lo, p);
  }
}
```